# How can I sort a specific dynamic range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that sorts on specific criteria, but I want certain rows to remain at the bottom of the sheet and be sorted by different criteria - thus requiring a 2nd sort function with a limited, dynamic sort range.

Here is a minimalised version of the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NCdMziBpj0joSv9lQfqT9etz9hMsvgMeuT8X9XTxR20/edit#gid=1466294505

I have modified code that finds the last populated column in a specific row with the intention of finding the row number of the last completed Quest (Where Col C checkbox is unticked), but it doesn't work as intended.  I have tried error-trapping with `Logger.log(lastCompleteQuest)` and `Logger.log(i)` to try and identify the problem, but they are not logging any values.

Here is the code:

```
  var lastCompleteQuest = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();

  for (var i=lastCompleteQuest;i>=1;i--){
    if(ss.getRange(i,activeCell.getCol()).getValue()!="TRUE") {break;}
  }
```

Below is the entire code for the `onEdit(e)` function.  When a checkbox is ticked/unticked it should:
  1. Sort the entire sheet based on the criteria in the code
  2. Sort the unticked rows based on the criteria in the code

The result should be that all ticked rows should be sorted primarily by Col A, while all unticked rows should remain at the bottom of the sheet and be sorted primarily by Col B.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Quests') { return; }
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.range.setNote('Completed: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
  else if (e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="FALSE") {
    e.range.clearNote();
  }

  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var sortRange = "A3:AN";
  var range     = ss.getRange(sortRange);
  var sortOrder = [
                  {column: 3, ascending: false},  // Sort the quests based on status with incomplete at the bottom
                  {column: 1, ascending: true}, // Sort all quests in chronological order (incomplete remain at bottom)
                  {column: 2, ascending: true} // To group incomplete quests based on region so they're easier to tick off
                  ];

  range.sort(sortOrder);


  var lastCompleteQuest = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();

  for (var i=lastCompleteQuest;i>=1;i--){
    if(ss.getRange(i,activeCell.getCol()).getValue()!="TRUE") {break;}
  }

  var newSortRow   = i+1;
  var newSortRange = "A"+newSortRow+":AN";
  var newRange     = ss.getRange(newSortRange);
  var newSortOrder = [
                     {column: 2, ascending: true}, // To group incomplete quests based on region so they're easier to tick off
                     {column: 1, ascending: true} // Then sort by chronological order
                     ];

  newRange.sort(newSortOrder);
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can offer some help instead of telling me what is wrong with my question.  If I knew why it didn't work, I obviously wouldn't have to be asking the question in the first place!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Please edit your question to improve it's problem description
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Per my comment on a previous question of yours, have you performed a *detailed* inspection of the specific data validation criteria your checkboxes use? Both *type* **and** *value*? To detect when the box is not checked, you must compare for equality with the checkbox DV's unchecked choice, or inequality with the checkbox DV's checked choice.

Comment: I DO NOT NEED TO IDENTIFY WHERE MY CHECKBOXES ARE.

It's pretty bloody obvious where they are.  It's also obvious what their states are because I have set them to default.

Are you just following me around the throw shade on me?  I'm doing my best here to learn how to code what I'm trying to achieve.  You're doing a great job at completely dissuading me (and no doubt others) in this pursuit.

I stated what I tried - I have set `Logger.log` to try and troubleshoot my code and it isn't returning a value.  I stripped the whole sheet and code down so someone could look at it very easily.

Comment: Why would I want to bloat my sheet with all the code in your Q&A page when I already know the location and states of the checkboxes?  It's great what you've written there, but completely irrelevant.  This place is a real kick in the teeth to anyone with a learning difficulty who is doing their absolute best.  Come here looking for help and just get constant criticism.

Comment: It's great that you are reviewing other posts. Please note that I asked you to include a rather specific response: exactly what **`valuetype`** and **`value`** are associated with your checkbox choices. The specifics of accessing a checkbox data validation rule & its choices are demonstrated in my aforementioned post. It's great you've added more description of your debugging efforts. When you post code, you can add or comment out the lines you used for debugging to help others understand exactly where you inspected its behavior. Also include whether you see errors logged in Stackdriver.

Comment: So turns out all I had to change was **.getValue()!="TRUE"** to **.getValue()!==false**.  These are kind of stupidly simple things someone with impaired visual learning struggles massively with.  I beat myself up about it enough as it is, I don't need a community I'm coming to get help from to add to that.

Answer (score 0):

tehhowch inspired me to keep smashing my head against the wall, and surprisingly I was able to come up with a solution basically though trial and error.  If anyone else is interested in creating dynamical range sorting for their spreadsheet, here is the code that works now for me:

```
  var lastCompleteQuest = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();

  for (var i=lastCompleteQuest;i>=1;i--){
    if(ss.getRange(i,3).getValue()!==false) {break;}
  }

  var newSortRow   = i+1;
  var newSortRange = "A"+newSortRow+":AN";
  var newRange     = ss.getRange(newSortRange);
  var newSortOrder = [
                     {column: 2, ascending: true}, // To group incomplete quests based on region so they're easier to tick off
                     {column: 1, ascending: true} // Then sort by chronological order
                     ];

  newRange.sort(newSortOrder);
```